# Общее количество товаров в корзине

Tags: opencart, корзина

В стандартном шаблоне OpenCart есть переменная $cart, которая выводит кнопку текущего состояния корзины пользователя. Здесь отображается общее количество товаров в корзине и общая сумма заказанных товаров.

Как вывести общее количество товаров в корзине, например, в шапке сайта?

Answer (score 3):

1. В файл /catalog/controller/common/header.php добавить в метод **index** след код:

   $this->data['cart_total'] = $this->cart->countProducts();
2. В Вашем шаблоне используйте переменную **$cart_total** для вывода кол-ва товаров.